# vmware error after removing disk

Tags: virtual-machine, disk, vmware-workstation

Environment: vmware VMware® Workstation 12 Pro (12.1.1 build-3770994) , running on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1.

A VM RHEL 7 with SCSI boot (virtual) disk is running on VMWare.

After previously adding and removing a secondary SATA virtual disk (.vmdk) the Red Hat VM is not booting with error message:

> File not found:  this file is required to power on this virtual machine...

There is a clean way to solve this, the disk has been added and removed from the virtual machine settings, section hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
The Rhel VM has a snapshot, and the snapshot's configuration had a reference to the removed disk.
So I edited the file vmsd of the VM (RHEL7_dev_64-bit.vmsd)
changing the config from this:

```
snapshot0.numDisks = "2"
snapshot0.disk0.fileName = "RHEL7_dev_64-bit-disk.vmdk"
snapshot0.disk0.node = "scsi0:0"
snapshot0.disk1.fileName = "Ubuntu 64-bit-s001.vmdk"
snapshot0.disk1.node = "sata0:0"
```

to this:

```
snapshot0.numDisks = "1"
snapshot0.disk0.fileName = "RHEL7_dev_64-bit-disk.vmdk"
snapshot0.disk0.node = "scsi0:0"
```